# Time stamp when a dde linked cell change

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in column 11 ( dde linked). I wish to have a time stamp when data changes in column 11 in column 12. Here is some code I have tried but not working as expected yet?

in sheet 1.....:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open(ByVal Target As Range)
Sheet1.ValDDE = Target.Column = 10
End Sub
```

in module 1 ........:

```
Public ValDDE
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)
If VarType(ValDDE) = VarType(Target.Column = 10) Then
If ValDDE <> Cells(Target.Column, 12).Value = Now Then _
  MsgBox "New value : " & Target.Column = 11 _
  Else Exit Sub
Else: MsgBox "New value : " & Target.Column = 11
End If
ValDDE = Target.Column = 11
End Sub
Sub ddetrackchange()

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Sheet1.ValDDE = Target.Column = 10` giving you the expected result? As normally `A = B = C` will give for A either `True` or `False` depending on whether `B = C` or not...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to remove 'calculate' method as it's one of those nasty performance slowing down *horcrux*.

Please try the following with `worksheet changed event`. You do not need to check on each cell in a range with a `for loop` if you only detecting one cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim myRng As Range
    Set myRng = Range("D2") 'change according to yours
    If Target.Application.DDEAppReturnCode = True 'this check the dde link updates specifically
      If Target.Address = myRng.Address Then        
         'change time in some other cell
         Range("E2").value = now()
      else
      'do something else
      End If
    else
    'do something else
    End If
End Sub
```

- [MSDN library reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836739.aspx)

Comment: HI bonCodigo.Please could you check your code, as there seems to be errors, and I cant seem to get it to run.